# How should I store user-uploaded images for a web application?

Tags: database, web-applications, filesystems, filenames, scalability

On my web server, I have two folders `showcase` and `thumbnail` to store images and their thumbnails, respectively. A database fetches these images to display them on a page.

The table column in the `showcase` table is `s_image` which stores something like `/showcase/urlcode.jpg`.

I heard that after around 10-20k files in a folder, it starts to slow down. So should I be creating a second folder, `showcase2` once it's filled up? Is there some kind of automatic creation that can do this for me?

I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

The filesystem you're using matters when you put tens of thousands of files in a single directory.  `extfs4` on Linux scales up better than NTFS on Windows.

Windows has a compatibility mode for 8.3 file names (the old-timey DOS file name standard). This causes every file name longer than `abcdefgh.ext` to have an alias created for it something like `abcd~123.ext`. This is slow, and gets *very* slow when you have lots of files in a single directory. You can turn off this ancient compatibility behavior. See here. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/121007.  If you do turn it off, it's a quick fix for an immediate performance problem.

But, 20,000 files in one directory is a large number. Your best bet, on any sort of file system, is automatically creating subdirectories in your file system based on something that changes.  One strategy is to create subdirectories based on year / month, for example

```
 /showcase/2015/08/image1.jpg  (for images uploaded this month)
 /showcase/2015/09/image7.jpg  (for images next month)
```

It's obviously no problem to store those longer file names in your `s_image` column in your table.

Or, if you have some system to the naming of the images, exploit it to create subdirectories. For example, if your images are named

```
 cat0001.jpg
 cat0002.jpb
 ...
 cat0456.jpg
 ...
 cat0987.jpg
```

You can create subdirectories based on, say, the first five letters of the names

```
 /showcase/cat00/cat0001.jpg
 /showcase/cat00/cat0002.jpb
 ...
 /showcase/cat04/cat0456.jpg
 ...
 /showcase/cat09/cat0987.jpg
```

If you do this, it's much better to keep the image names intact rather than make them shorter (for example, don't do this `/showcase/cat09/87.jpg`) because if you have to search for a particular image by name you want the full name there.

As far as I know, there's nothing automatic in a file system to do this for you. But it's not hard to do in your program.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I'm going to try out Amazon S3 for now and see what I can do.

Comment: Even in S3 you don't want tens of thousands of items in one directory in a bucket.